# API to translate US English to UK English

Tags: translation, google-translate, bing-translator-api

Google Translate and Bing Translator does not support US English to UK English.

Do you know any API to translate US English to UK English?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could investigate, idiomatic translation doesn't seem to be supported by any translate API. Nonetheless, I think your question is very valid and in the future an idiomatic translator could be implemented for these translation services

There is  a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111111247) for such goal in the public issue tracker of Google if you would like to keep track of it.